# TypeError: res.on is not a function, this error is coming when ran test cases using jest on my firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I am writing firebase cloud functions using v2 of cloud functions, and had to write its test cases using jest. But i am getting this 'TypeError: res.on is not a function' and my test case fails.

This is my cloud function:

```
import { handler, checkgethttp } from '../middlewares'
export const getUserDetails = functions.https.onRequest({ cors: true }, async (req: any, res: any) => {
  handler(req, res, [checkgethttp])
  try {
    const allData = await (await db().collection('users').get()).docs
    let userData = allData.map((v) => v.data())

    if (userData) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Success',
        data: userData,
      })
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'no record found',
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: error?.message })
  }
})
```

and this is my test case:

```
describe('getuser function', () => {
  const req = {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  }

  const res = {
    status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    json: jest.fn(),

  }
  test('function should be defined and callable', async () => {
    await getUserDetails(req, res)
    expect(getUserDetails).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

but it is getting failed, and tried removing the `{ cors: true }` from the cloud function's first argument than it is passing all the test cases, but fails otherwise.

I think it is important to use `{ cors: true }` to define the respective cors origin, but not able to solve this test case issue.

Comment: I have same error. Did u find the solution?

Comment: Hey, @J.Dragon sorry for being ghost for a long time, I did not find an exact solution for it, but i have tried removing { cors: true } from it, and to my shock it doesn’t affect my cloud functions at all.